# Browser displays / executes alert for form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, xss

I have got a cross site scripting issue.
I have a child modal dialog with textarea field and Save button. Now if the user enters alert("1") tag for this field and clicks on Save, I close the modal dialog and display this in the background modal div (i.e. on parent modal)

This actually happens through triggering an event via Backbone and I paste the response (which is nothing but what the user had entered in the field)

```
$("#myFieldDiv").html(resp);
```

Now the browser is showing popup with value 1. How can I fix this ?

My field need to accept HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using encodeURIComponent() to encode the input from the user.

```
$("#myFieldDiv").html(encodeURIComponent(resp));
```